# Typescript not compiling due to version number

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, typescript2.0, typescript1.8

I have two instances of Visual Studio installed. 2015, and 2017. I have a project that requires `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>` to run. When I publish this project in VS2015, TypeScript doesn't compile.

When checking the `tsc -v`, I noticed that it is `v. 2.4.1`.

I have a hunch that the cuase of my issue is the difference of version numbers in `tsc`. Could that be the case? If so, I'm afraid the only possible solution to publish this project is to remove VS2017. Is that right?

Comment: No, that is not correct. Install [TypeScript  for Visual Studio](http://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html#download-links). Install both the 2015 and 2017 versions and you should be good. Make sure you upgrade the version in your project as well: `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`. Also, Visual Studio does not put `tsc` into your path. That likely comes from a global installation via npm.

Comment: I can't upgrade the version of `TypeScrip` in my solution because of ownership restriction.

Comment: Your best bet is to go to "Programs and Features" and remove all installations of "TypeScript tools for Visual Studio", run `npm uninstall -g typescript` and use some other editor, such as VS Code, which lets you use any version you want, while you wait for the actual owner of the project to get with the times. You can also try disabling all TypeScript related settings in Visual Studio and uninstalling it using the Visual Studio Installer that manages VS 2017

Comment: I don't want to uninstall anything. I was able to find the solve this problem. I answered it below. Please vote up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, Go to **Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management**. Make sure the following three tools are added and sorted accordingly.

1. .\node_modules.bin - Solution will look into `node_modules` to find `typescript`. If this fails..
2. $(PATH) - It will look for the version of `typescript` in the `Environment Path`. If this fails..
3. $(VSINSTALLDIR)\web\External - It will look for the version of `typescript` in the installed directory of VisualStudio.

[image]

In the package.json, add `"typescript": "1.8.10"`. Run `npm install` or `Install all packages` using Grunt.